# I have duplicate IDs in a data set, and would like to keep the one with the least amount of NAs across the data columns

Tags: r, duplicates, na

I have a data frame that has duplicate IDS. I want to keep the ID that has the least amount of NAs (so the most complete set for the ID). In this example i would want to keep the second 123 and the second 124 (lease NAs)

I can identify the duplicates but I cant write a code to essentially say
1)For each duplicate, keep the one with less NAs
The code could also say
2)For each duplicate, remove the one with more NAs,

Here is example data

```
id    Col1    col1 2   col 3  col 4
123   10       NA       NA     3
123   50       3        2      NA
124   30       5        7      NA 
124   30       8        1      2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort by the number of `NA`s in each row and then remove duplicates:

```r
require(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(rowSums(is.na(df))) %>% filter(!duplicated(id)) %>% arrange(id)

   id Col1 col2 col3 col4
1 123   50    3    2   NA
2 124   30    8    1    2
```

Data:

```r
df = read.table(text='id Col1 col2 col3 col4
123   10       NA       NA     3
123   50       3        2      NA
124   30       5        7      NA
124   30       8        1      2', header = T, strip.white = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[order(rowSums(is.na(df))), head(.SD, 1), by = id]

# id Col1 col2 col3 col4
# 1: 124   30    8    1    2
# 2: 123   50    3    2   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   slice(which.min(rowSums(is.na(cur_data())))) %>%
   ungroup
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#     id  Col1  col2  col3  col4
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1   123    50     3     2    NA
#2   124    30     8     1     2
```

---

Or using `c_across`

```
df %>%
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(cnt = sum(is.na(c_across(-id)))) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  arrange(id, cnt) %>%
  distinct(id, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(123L, 123L, 124L, 124L), Col1 = c(10L, 
50L, 30L, 30L), col2 = c(NA, 3L, 5L, 8L), col3 = c(NA, 2L, 7L, 
1L), col4 = c(3L, NA, NA, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: and similar to the first: `df %>% group_by(id) %>% top_n(-1, rowSums(is.na(cur_data()))) %>% ungroup`